# Showing a particular div after page redirect

Tags: jquery, html, css, redirect

I have a HTML similar to below:

```
<div id="first"> FIirst Div</div>
<div id="second"> Second Div</div>
<div id="third"> Third Div</div>

<a href="#" id="one">View First Div</a>
<a href="#" id="two">View Second Div</a>
<a href="#" id="three">View Third Div</a>
```

And the CSS and Jquery :

```
#second,#third {
    display:none;
}

$('#one').click(function(){
 $('#first').show();
 $('#second').hide();
 $('#third').hide();
 });

$('#two').click(function(){
 $('#first').hide();
 $('#second').show();
 $('#third').hide();
 });

$('#three').click(function(){
 $('#first').hide();
 $('#second').hide();
 $('#third').show();
 });
```

So the above code will show the div id `third` if we click `View Third Div` for example. Now if I redirect the page to itself, it will be back to its original properties and shows the first div. I want to know is there any method/technique in which I can show the div I need after redirecting for the above structure ?

Comment: Add jquery link in the page. For Example <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while redirecting use a `hash` value in your `URI` about the active `DIV`

**eg** : `www.yoururl.com/sumthing#ActiveDiv=div123`

```
$(function(){
var activediv = $(location).attr('hash'); //get the active div

......CODE to make active your DIV now...............

})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can redirect to same page but with some url parameter. 
This parameter can be used to determine if show div or not.
Just instead

> http://mypageurl.com/page.html use
>   http://mypageurl.com/page.html?showDiv=true

You can read parameters even with javascript not only by serverside code. Here is how to do it with [jQuery](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/url-parameters-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement that:
 1. The simple way. Add one parameter into the redirect URL. When redirecting to the page, use js to analyse the URL and invoke corresponding function to show the properties;
2. The complex way. When you click to show corresponding properties, send a ajax request and record which properties you are reading by session. When visit this page again, use session information to decide which properties to show.

Answer (score 1):

While redirecting page, you can pass div_id to show, and In html page you can use javascript to get URL parameter name and show div accordingly.

```
<script>
function getParam(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
     url = window.location.href;
    }
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
    if (!results) { 
        return 0; 
    }
    return results[1] || 0;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var div_id=getParam("div_id");
    if(div_id!=0){
        //hide all  (you could add common class_name for div to hide-all at once)
       $("#first").hide();
       $("#second").hide();
       $("#third").hide();

       $("#"+div_id).show(); //show div which id is passed in url parameter
    }
});
```

**while redirecting**

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/pagename.html?div_id=third                [This will show third div on page reload]
```